# Web API C# .net: cannot convert the model in the dto in get method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

As I said in the title, I'm trying to convert in the get method a model object to its DTO.

My method is to get users and is the next piece of code:

```
// GET: api/Users
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UserDTO>>> GetUsers()
{
    var users = _context.Users.ToList();
    var userDtos = new List<UserDTO>();
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        userDtos.Add(new UserDTO 
        { 
            IdUser = user.UserProfessionId, 
            UserName = user.UserName, 
            UserCompany = user.UserCompany, 
            UserMail = user.UserMail, 
            UserProfession = user.UserProfession, 
            UserProfessionField = user.UserProfessionField 
        });
    }
    return userDtos;
}
```

These are my model and DTO for user:

```
namespace Sims.Models
{
    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            DataUsages = new HashSet<DataUsage>();
        }

        public long IdUser { get; set; }
        public int UserProfessionId { get; set; }
        public int UserProfessionFieldId { get; set; }
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public string? UserMail { get; set; }
        public string? UserCompany { get; set; }
        public byte[]? UserPicture { get; set; }

        public virtual Profession UserProfession { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ProfessionField UserProfessionField { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<DataUsage> DataUsages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace sims.DTO
{
    public partial class UserDTO
    {
        public long IdUser { get; set; }
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public string? UserMail { get; set; }
        public string? UserCompany { get; set; }

        public virtual ProfessionDTO UserProfession { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ProfessionFieldDTO UserProfessionField { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

Profession and ProfessionField are also models and have their own DTO. But in the get method, the two following lines contain the same error as it "cannot implicitly convert type '....Models.Profession' to '....DTO.ProfessionDTO'".

Do you have any idea ?

In case, here is an example of the Profession Model and DTO:

```
namespace Sims.Models
{
    public partial class Profession
    {
        public Profession()
        {
            ProfessionFields = new HashSet<ProfessionField>();
            Users = new HashSet<User>();
        }

        public int IdProfession { get; set; }
        public string ProfessionName { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual ICollection<ProfessionField> ProfessionFields { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace sims.DTO
{
    public class ProfessionDTO
    {
        public int IdProfession { get; set; }
        public string ProfessionName { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UserProfession` property is of type `ProfessionDTO`:

```
public virtual ProfessionDTO UserProfession { get; set; } = null!;
```

But you're trying to populate it with an object of type `Profession`:

```
UserProfession = user.UserProfession,
```

Just as the error states, they are different types and can't be substituted for one another.  Populate the property with an instance of `ProfessionDTO` instead:

```
UserProfession = new UserProfessionDTO
{
    IdProfession = user.UserProfession.IdProfession,
    ProfessionName = user.UserProfession.ProfessionName
},
```

---

If the `user.UserProfession` field is `null` then you'd need to check for that.  For example:

```
UserProfession = user.UserProfession == null ?
    null as UserProfessionDTO :
    new UserProfessionDTO
    {
        IdProfession = user.UserProfession?.IdProfession,
        ProfessionName = user.UserProfession?.ProfessionName
    },
```

Comment: I've tried doing this like [this](https://pastebin.com/qgC9pips) but I have an error 500 for a NullReferenceException due to object reference not set to an instance of an object when I add an userDTO object to the liste userDtos

Comment: @Cucumberbatch: Sounds like some of your data may have a `null` value for the `UserProfession` property then.  I've updated te answer with an option for that.  Overall the principle remains the same.  You simply need to construct and object (or use `null`) of the correct type for the property.

Comment: I just tried and it seems that it returns null for profession and professionfield everytime

Comment: @Cucumberbatch: That would imply that `UserProfession` is `null` for every record.  When you debug, do you observe anything indicating otherwise?  It could be a problem in the data, or possibly a problem in the ORM configuration, or just that there are no such values in the database.

Comment: Ok I just checked by debugging and the ids for Profession and ProfessionField are both 0 for every instance of user but it's not the case in the database

Comment: @Cucumberbatch: In that case that sounds like a separate issue unrelated to the type issue asked above.  Your next step would be to do some more investigation and, if stuck, formulate a separate Stack Overflow question with informatino about that issue.

Comment: I'll do that ! thanks for the help :)

Comment: Weird thing, I tried out of curiosity what you told me for the get by id method and it works !